# Showing a div using the value of a checkbox with reference variable in angular

Tags: angular, checkbox

I am trying to toggle a div's visibility using a checkbox. I am trying to do this using reference variable, but could not figure out how to do it. I am trying to do something like below. I can`t get the checkbox value.

```
<input #changePasswordSwitch class="switch-input"  name="changePassword" id="changePassword" type="checkbox" >

<div class="form-group row" *ngIf="changePasswordSwitch.value">
   Show Some Data Here 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ngModel` on input and change for `changePasswordSwitch.checked`:

```
<input #changePasswordSwitch [ngModel]="changePasswordSwitchModel" class="switch-input" name="changePassword" id="changePassword"
 type="checkbox">
<div class="form-group row" *ngIf="changePasswordSwitch.checked">
    Show Some Data Here
</div>
```

or drop the template variable and go with only two-way bound `ngModel`:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="changePasswordSwitchModel" class="switch-input" name="changePassword" id="changePassword" type="checkbox">
<div class="form-group row" *ngIf="changePasswordSwitchModel">
    Show Some Data Here
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcx1rq)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering why do we need ngModel in this case and can not access it with only using #changePasswordSwitch ?

Comment: @Vega, not use "value", use "checked"

Comment: @Eliseo, yes, that's what I did

Comment: Ok (I have a bad day), that's work even if you write some stupid like < input #mycheck **(change)="null"**  type="checkbox">